# Mitmatched character accents in French / Spanish HTML loaded in WP7 browser

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, encoding

I'm having trouble loading a local French / Spanish HTML within Windows Phone 7. the accent é becomes ýý in the BrowserControl within on the phone. they used to be an unrecognised symbol  before I removed formatting in the html file. I hope the image help understand the problem, I can't seem to find the reason why it's changing.

[image: Accent Character Mismatch]

here's the offending sample html repro

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />
<title>Acteur majeur du commerce en lig</title>
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style3 {
    font-size: small;
}
.auto-style4 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #DDDDDD">

<p class="auto-style4"><strong>Charte de sécurité </strong></p>
<p><span><span class="auto-style1"><span class="auto-style3">Acteur majeur du 
commerce en ligne, leader des voyages et loisirs en France et en Europe, 
lastminute.com oeuvre au quotidien pour garantir une sécurité maximale de ses 
transactions ainsi que l'intégrité et la confidentialité des données de ses 
visiteurs et abonnés. lastminute.com s'associe donc tout naturellement, depuis 
le vendredi 3 juin 2005,&nbsp;à la Délégation aux usages de l'internet du Ministère 
de l'Éducation nationale, de l'Enseignement supérieur et de la Recherche et au 
Sénat pour lancer la première semaine pour la sécurité sur Internet. Pour que le 
web reste un formidable lieu d'échange, de convivialité et d'interactivité, et 
parce que &quot;l'internet + sûr, ça s'apprend&quot;, découvrez vite tous les bons 
réflexes sur&nbsp;</span><a href="http://protegetonordi.com/"><span class="auto-style3">protegetonordi.com</span></a><span class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</span></span></span></p>

</body>

</html>
```

I took this into Expression Web, and saved it as a HTML file to use locally, within the WP7 app. i marked the HTML as Content, and loaded it using the code below

```
        StreamReader terms = new StreamReader(TitleContainer.
           OpenStream("html/terms.html"));  
        browserControl.NavigateToString(terms.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: What encoding does the file have? What encoding does the BrowserControl think the file has?

Comment: I'm new at this. I've set the encoding to None, and I changed them to central Europe but it didn't work. also, there was an option to set country of origin in Expression Web - Didn't help.

How do I setup the browsercontrol for this?

Comment: Central Europe encoding is for polish, czech, etc French and spanish is encoded with Western Europe encoding (iso-8859-1 or 15 with € / Windows-1252). Unrelated, Central European Time (CET) is used by Spain, France, Poland, ... maybe this is the source of your confusion

Comment: removing encoding, or setting it to western european encoding didn't seem to help.

Comment: Please provide an example HTML file (minimal content) which enables recreating this issue.

Comment: Looks like a larger HTML file causes screen - flickers in a lower end Device like the HTC trophy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd "guess" that your original file is saved as ASCII but the characters that aren't displaying are non-ASCII and that you don't have any encoding information in the HTML headers.

Try re-saving the file as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all non-Ascii characters have turned to “ýÿ”, so apparently there are several problems involved. The two characters have ISO-8859-1 codes 0xFD 0xFF, and these two bytes are the UTF-16LE (“byte-swapped”, or Little-Endian, 16-bit transformation format for Unicode) encoding of U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, which is commonly used to indicate data error at the character level.

So some software fails to interpret the text data properly and replaces offending characters by U+FFFD, which then gets UTF-16LE encoded and later misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1. The original encoding of the data should be identified first, and possibly the data needs to be converted to ISO-8859-1 *or* treated consistently as UTF-8.

Comment: How do I do that? especially in a WP7 web browsercontrol? sorry I'm not used to localization.

Comment: Where should I look for it, I created the HTML myself, from some source that I was given. what should I change?

Comment: The answer was obvious and simple, thanks to Matt Lacey - I misunderstood Jukka's answer as well. the file must be saved as UTF8 rather than just setting encoding options in the metatags